# Как поменять данные в JSON из Python?

Tags: python, json

Есть некий валидный JSON-файлик. Пример:

```
{
    "example": ["test1", "test2"]
    
}
```

Как можно поменять значение конкретного элемента/ключа (напр., test1) на Python. Или реализовать полное чтение, изменение в дампе и перезапись

Answer (score 3):

Используйте модуль `json`, который идет "из коробки":

```py
import json

JSON = '''
{
    "example": ["test1", "test2"]
    
}
'''

print(json.loads(JSON)["example"][0]) 
# Тут мы читаем json и получаем значение ключа "example", 
# потом берем элемент 0 и выводим его через print() в консоль.
```

Answer (score 0):

Согласен  с [@Никита](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/452438/%d0%9d%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0), что для корректной работы и сохранения всех правил JSON'a вам необходимо пользоваться стандартым модулем `json`.

Когда вы получаете JSON, то для Python это всегда строки или последовательность бит. И этот тип данных вы можете конвертировать в словарь Python, при помощи

```py
dict_from_json = json.loads(JSON)
```

После этого переменная `dict_from_json` будет содержать понятный для Python словарь (тип данных dict). То есть вот на этом этапе у вас появляется возможность обращаться к словарю по ключам и изменять значения в нем.

После того как вы сделали изменения и вы хотите сохранить структуру JSON, то вам необходимо воспользоваться обратной операцией и сделать следующее

```py
updated_json = json.dumps(dict_from_json)
```

После этой операции `updated_json` будет содержать строку, как JSON.

Все это нужно для того, чтобы не нарушать структуры и следовать типам данных, которые различаются в Python и JSON. [Различия вот здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#py-to-json-table) можно глянуть.

И если все собрать вместе, то мы получим

```py
import json
JSON = '''
{
    "example": ["test1", "test2"]
    
}
'''
dict_from_json = json.loads(JSON) # dict
dict_from_json.get("example")[0] = True # меняю значение
print(f"Словарь такой: {dict_from_json}")
json_from_dict = json.dumps(dict_from_json)
print(f"А вот JSON такой:{json_from_dict}")
```

Вывод

```
Словарь такой: {'example': [True, 'test2']}
А вот JSON такой:{"example": [true, "test2"]}
```

Можете обратить внимание, что поскольку JSON понимает только двойные кавычки, то словарь как результат не будет удовлетворять этому условию. И так же я добавил одно булево значение, чтобы стало понятно, о чем это я тут разглагольствую

Answer (score -1):

"example" - это ключ словаря.

["test1", "test2"] - это обычный список, доступ к которому идет по ключу словаря. Доступ к каждому элементу списка - масса, например, по индексу(самый примитивный):

```
dict_name["example"][0] = new_data
```

Comment: Если я добавляю [0], то он отображает у меня [, а если [1], то кавычку

Comment: А всё разобрался, спасибо, у меня почему-то после сохранения изменялась структура json

Comment: Абсолютно не так. Для Python'a JSON - это просто биты или строка, как тип данных. И для того чтобы вопользоваться `example` как ключом, необходимо привести JSON в удобоваримый и понятный тип данных для Python. Просто ответьте на вопрос, в чем отличие `false` и `False`? Ответ: что одно валидно для JSON, а другое для Python. Для этого и существует модуль `json` в стандартном наборе Python, чтобы представлять валидные данные JSON в валидные данные Python, и наоборот.